# SQL - Select rows with values greater than max value for id and category

Tags: sql, oracle

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| Product ID | Part Sequence | Part Material |  Description   |
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|          1 |             1 | Steel         | Part A         |
|          1 |             2 | CFK           | Part B         |
|          1 |             3 | CFK           | Part B Variant |
|          1 |             4 | Steel         | Part C         |
|          1 |             5 | GFK           | Part D         |
|          1 |             6 | Plastic       | Part E         |
|          2 |             1 | Steel         | Part A         |
|          2 |             2 | CFK           | Part B         |
|          2 |             3 | Steel         | Part F         |
|          2 |             4 | CFK           | Part B         |
|          2 |             5 | Steel         | Part G         |
|          2 |             6 | Silicon       | Part D+        |
|          2 |             7 | Plastic       | Part E         |
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

(the ordering by Product ID and Part Sequence is only done for readability, my db table is unorderd)

I need to query all rows for each product id with a part sequence equal or higher to the last steel part.

So for the table above the expected result would be:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| Product ID | Part Sequence | Part Material |  Description   |
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|          1 |             4 | Steel         | Part C         |
|          1 |             5 | GFK           | Part D         |
|          1 |             6 | Plastic       | Part E         |
|          2 |             5 | Steel         | Part G         |
|          2 |             6 | Silicon       | Part D+        |
|          2 |             7 | Plastic       | Part E         |
+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I could use the solution from [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column FILTERED by Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245008/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column-filtered-by-column) to find the last steel part and then filter anything with a higher part sequence, but I'm hoping for a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a windowed aggregate function (requiring only a single pass over the table) rather than using a join (which will require two passes over the table):

[It will also return products where there are no steel parts - if this is an issue then a similar windowed query can be use to filter those rows out.]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3a24/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( Product_ID, Part_Sequence, Part_Material, Description ) AS
          SELECT 1, 1, 'Steel',   'Part A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 'CFK',     'Part B' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3, 'CFK',     'Part B Variant' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 4, 'Steel',   'Part C' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 5, 'GFK',     'Part D' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 6, 'Plastic', 'Part E' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'Steel',   'Part A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'CFK',     'Part B' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 'Steel',   'Part F' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4, 'CFK',     'Part B' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 5, 'Steel',   'Part G' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 6, 'Silicon', 'Part D+' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 7, 'Plastic', 'Part E' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'Silicon', 'Part A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'Plastic', 'Part B' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Product_ID,
       Part_Sequence,
       Part_Material,
       Description
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COALESCE(
           SUM( CASE Part_Material WHEN 'Steel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY Product_ID
                    ORDER BY Part_Sequence
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ),
           0
         ) AS isInvalid
  FROM   TEST t
)
WHERE  isInvalid = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3a24/1/0)**:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | PART_SEQUENCE | PART_MATERIAL | DESCRIPTION |
|------------|---------------|---------------|-------------|
|          1 |             4 |         Steel |      Part C |
|          1 |             5 |           GFK |      Part D |
|          1 |             6 |       Plastic |      Part E |
|          2 |             5 |         Steel |      Part G |
|          2 |             6 |       Silicon |     Part D+ |
|          2 |             7 |       Plastic |      Part E |
|          3 |             1 |       Silicon |      Part A |
|          3 |             2 |       Plastic |      Part B |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
Select * from product  
join 

(Select Max(Part_Sequence) as sequence,productid from product 
group by Productid, Part Sequence) d

on product.Part_Sequence = d.sequence
and product.productid = d.productid
```

if you want query for specific part just apply where clause to inner and outer query for that part

Comment: `product.[Part Sequence]` is an invalid identifier in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t1.* from table as t1 inner join 
(
select product_id,max(Part_Sequence) as Part_Sequence from table as t 
where Part_Material='Steel'
group by product_id
)  t2 on t1.product_id=t2.product_id
where t1.Part_Sequence>=t2.Part_Sequence
```

Comment: I thought it is SQL Server. Corrected it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of distinct `product_id` is low compared to the number of rows in the table, then using a join might perform well (otherwise the solution with a window function will be faster):

```
select p.*
from parts p
 join (
   select product_id, max(part_sequence) as max_seq
   from parts 
   where part_material = 'Steel'
   group by product_id
  ) t on t.product_id = p.product_id and p.part_sequence >= t.max_seq
```

Note that this will not return parts where there is no row with `part_material = 'Steel'`. I don't know if that is a possible scenario or not.